# Can I use 'vice versa' in this sentence?

Tags: grammar, adverbs

*The older they get, the more dogs become popular. As for cats, vice versa.*

What I want to say is: "Older people love dogs. Younger people love cats."

Comment: Your example of what you want to say is probably as good a way of saying it as anything. The first sentence doesn't seem a good way of expressing that idea, but not necessarily because of the use of _vice versa_. To me, without more context, "_The older they get, the more dogs become popular_" implies that as _dogs_ get older, they get more popular (i.e. people prefer old dogs to puppies).

Comment: _Vice versa_ isn't the issue in the example given. I had to read it three times before I understood that the initial _they_ is not the dogs. Re-cast a clearer example.

Comment: It seems that I have to revise the use of a pronoun. I used 'they' as a pronoun of 'people', but sure it was so confusing and you are totally right. Thank you for pointing that out.

Comment: *The older people get, the more dogs become popular with them.* If you make that change, the question about *vice versa* will make sense.

Answer (score 0):

According to Oxford Living Dictionary VICE VERSA is an adverb and means 'with the main items in the preceding statement the other way round':
‘cruise from Cairo to Aswan or vice versa’
Or:
‘But Clay knows I know him better than anyone else possibly could, and vice versa.
So the use of 'vice versa' is acceptable.
The problem may be with the first sentence itself.
Does the pronoun 'they' substitute 'people' or 'animals'?

Comment: Thank you for your answer, I used 'they' as a pronoun of 'people'.